# Are IntelliSense features available in Data Studio?

Tags: windows, autocomplete, db2, intellisense, ibm-data-studio

Does IBM Data Studio have `IntelliSense features` or [Intelligent code completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_code_completion) something
like below?

I would like to write an SQL query with IntelliSense type functionality.

I have IBM Data Studio 4.1.3

[image: IntelliSense features]

Comment: You may press `Ctrl+space` to get context help.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein it is really nice, but need to press 'Ctrl+space' always . I am looking for auto suggestion function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, IBM Data Studio does not support `IntelliSense features`.